# Binding proxy data not being bound

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, converters

I am using a binding proxy to store a calculated value which is used multiple times in an XAML file.

I am using this code for the proxy itself:

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get { return GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Data), typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

A proxy is then created in the User control resources like so:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary>

                <view_common:BindingProxy x:Key="EllipseDiameter">
                    <view_common:BindingProxy.Data>
                        <MultiBinding>
                            <MultiBinding.Converter>
                                <conv:ChainMultiConverter>
                                    <conv:ChainMultiConverter.Converter1>
                                        <conv:MaxDoublesConverter/>
                                    </conv:ChainMultiConverter.Converter1>
                                    <conv:ChainMultiConverter.Converter2>
                                        <conv:MultiplyDoubleConverter Value="2"/>
                                    </conv:ChainMultiConverter.Converter2>
                                </conv:ChainMultiConverter>
                            </MultiBinding.Converter>
                            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                <Binding Path="Dimentions.Height"/>
                                <Binding Path="Dimentions.Width"/>
                            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </view_common:BindingProxy.Data>
                </view_common:BindingProxy>

            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    
</UserControl.Resources>
```

As you can see the two values get chained through a few converters. So rather than doing all this processing multiple times I thought I would put the calculations here.

This value is then used like so:

```
<Ellipse Grid.Row="1"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Stroke="Black" Fill="LightGray" 
            Opacity=".25"
            Height="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource EllipseDiameter}}"
            Width="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource EllipseDiameter}}"/>
```

However on starting the program I get an error saying

```
DoubleConverter cannot convert from (null).
```

And the converters for the binding up in the binding proxy are never invoked. How come the value is not calculated first? The Ellipse is trying to bind to the value before the value has been calculated.

That chain of converters works just fine when used directly by the Height and Width values of the ellipse. So there isn't an issue I know of with the conversion.

Comment: `Dimentions` looks like a typo. Shouldn't it be `Dimensions`?

Comment: No, that is a spelling error which is consistent across the code base, I shall have to fix that. The property it is binding to is spelt "Dimentions"

Comment: You are passing a default value of `null` in your `UIPropertyMetadata` which is presumably unhandled in your `DoubleConverter`. You could try adding a check for `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` in your converter.

Comment: I don't have a DoubleConverter. I would think it is the built in Object-to-Double converter, since the value I am setting is height and width, which is a double. I just tried to see if I could set the default value to DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, but that threw an error saying the default value cannot be Unset.